# Check if substring exists in a list containing booleans?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, algorithm

I want to check if a substring exists in a list. But i can't iterate through it because of it having booleans. I'm trying to convert booleans to str(booleans) but is that necessary? I'm sure there must be another efficient way without changing data
[image: error]

```
def replace_falseTrue_as_strings(lst):
    for i in lst:
        if isinstance(i,list):
            for j in i:
                if all(not isinstance(j,list)):
                    for k in j:
                        k_new.append(str(k))
                    return k
                if any(isinstance(j,list)):
                    return replace_falseTrue_as_strings(j)
        else:
            i_new.append(str(i))
            return j_new
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew need them. Thanks all for your comments. Should have tried harder with the isinstance.

Comment: Depending on your needs, you could also use `any(needle in s for s in map(str, haystack))`. That would accept `True` if you searched for `"rue"`, and the integer `1234` if you searched for `"23"`. That might or might not be desired, depending on context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a typecheck:

```py
any( (isinstance(x, str) and 'abl' in x) for x in some_list)
```

in case of `x` not being a string (a boolean here), `isinstance(x, str)` is False and the second member is not checked, this avoids the TypeError.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
any('abl' in x for x in your_list if isinstance(x, str))
```

It checks the type of each item of your list and proceeds only if it's a string.